# devtools addressing nonexisting package

Tags: r, devtools

I am experiencing a problem with devtools
Somehow, it thinks I somewhere tried to  build a package neuwirth,
but it gives inconsisgtent information about this.
How can I get rid of this reference to a nonexisting package?

```
> packageVersion("devtools")
[1] ‘1.11.1’
> devtools::update_packages()
Skipping 1 unavailable package: neuwirth
```

Comment: Try `remove.packages("neuwirth")` and then try updating once more

Answer (score 0):

In fact, this seemed to he intended behavior with the CRAN version of devtools. When no package argument was given, it used the current directory name as argument. This has changed in the version on github. Now, when not package name is given as an argument, it will check all installed packages and update when necessary.